# Golang import package inside package

Tags: go, package

Go structure:

```
|--main.go
|
|--users
     |
     |---users.go
```

The two files are very simple:
main.go:

```
package main

import "./users"

func main() {
    resp := users.GetUser("abcde")
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

users.go:

```
package users

import "fmt"

func GetUser(userTok string) string {
    fmt.Sprint("sf")
    return "abcde"
}
```

But it seems fmt is not accessible in main.go. When I try to run the program, it gives

```
undefined: fmt in fmt.Println
```

Anybody knows how to make fmt accessible in main.go?

Comment: Go, is based on "has a" relationship, hence when using users in main, fmt package from users is not available to main and need to be imported explicitly in main.

Comment: You shouldn't use relative import paths if you want the standard build tools to work with your project.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `fmt` in `main` as well.

Simply write `"fmt"` in `import()` in `main.go` and it should run.

```
import(    
    "fmt"  
    "./users"
)
```