# golang package import failed

Tags: go, import, package

I have following folder structure in my project folder. `vendor` folder added as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480623/how-to-import-local-packages-in-go).

```
my_project
   |
   main.go
   - vendor
       |
       - user_register
           | 
           - user_register.go
```

In `user_register.go` I have following function

```
func getEmail(register_response http.ResponseWriter, register_request *http.Request) {
...
}
```

When I try to import `user_register` package in my `main.go`, it gives an error.

I tried `go install` from my project folder, and I got

> go install: no install location for directory
>   /home/sachith/Documents/Personal/Projects/my_project outside
>   GOPATH

Is there a way to solve this problem? Without moving my project into `/home/sachith/go` directory?

I have refereed following SO threads, but they didnt solve my problem.
[Golang import package inside package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101360/golang-import-package-inside-package)

[Golang import package error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190032/golang-import-package-error)

Comment: What is your `GOPATH` set to?

Comment: @lggy `GOPATH="/home/sachith/go"`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to solve this problem? Without moving my project into [GOPATH]?

Yes: Use Go modules by turning `GO111MODULE=on`.

Comment: Tried, but still no luck.